# Codeigniter double rows result when using mysql join in model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm working on codeigniter web app and I was doing some JOIN on model to show specific data from 3 tables but it gives me double row which should be only 1 row per data. It didn't happen when I only have 1 row data in my database but when I input the second data, it showed me 2 rows per data so I have 4 rows

The table name is **siswa** and I want to JOIN another table

This is the model for JOIN the database

```php
function delete_siswa($id)
    {
        return $this->db->delete('siswa',array('id'=>$id));
    }
    function get_data_siswa()
    {
        $this->db->select('sw.id, sw.nama, sw.j_kelamin, sw.tmp_lahir, sw.tgl_lahir, sw.agama, sw.alamat, sw.no_tlp, sw.email, ot.n_ibu, ot.n_ayah, sk.nama_sek');
        $this->db->from('siswa sw');
        $this->db->join('orang_tua ot', 'ot.id=sw.id_orang_tua');
        $this->db->join('sekolah sk', 'sk.id=sw.id_sekolah');
        return $this->db->get('siswa')->result_array();
    }
```

This is the controllers

```php
function index()
    {
        $data['siswa'] = $this->Siswa_model->get_data_siswa();

        $data['_view'] = 'siswa/index';
        $this->load->view('layouts/main',$data);
    }
```

This is the view

```php
<tr>
                                    <th>No</th>
                                    <th>Nama</th>
                                    <th>Jenis Kelamin</th>
                                    <th>Tempat Lahir</th>
                                    <th>Tanggal Lahir</th>
                                    <th>Agama</th>
                                    <th>Alamat</th>
                                    <th>No. Telepon</th>
                                    <th>Ibu</th>
                                    <th>Ayah</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Nama Sekolah</th>
                                    <th>Actions</th>
                                 </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <?php
                                    $no=1;
                                    foreach($siswa as $s){ ?>
                                    <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $no++;?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $s['nama']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $s['j_kelamin']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $s['tmp_lahir']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $s['tgl_lahir']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $s['agama']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $s['alamat']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $s['no_tlp']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $s['n_ibu']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $s['n_ayah']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $s['email']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $s['nama_sek']; ?></td>
                                    <td>
                                    <a class="btn btn-warning" href="<?php echo site_url('siswa/edit/'.$s['id']); ?>">Edit</a> | 
                                    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="<?php echo site_url('siswa/remove/'.$s['id']); ?>">Delete</a>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </tbody>
```

[**This is the screenshoot of this error**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Wg1w.jpg)

It should be only one row per data but I don't really know because I'm still new for codeigniter. No error in the log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you take the distinct record from the table, i think the join query will duplicate the data

```
$this->db->distinct();
```

will work for this

Comment: So I have to put the this on my model?

Comment: just give a try